# Java look and feel for tray does not work

Tags: java, look-and-feel, system-tray, tray

I use `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` to set a LAF and it works fine. But this time I also implemented a tray and it looks ugly - like Motif. How can I set LAF for the tray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you're probably using for this is java.awt.SystemTray.

The tray uses AWT, not Swing. You cant set the look and feel of it.

I think there is a duplicate of this somewhere on here.

Comment: These helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600638/java-look-and-feel-for-tray-messages-on-ubuntu and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java